# Trying to move a div from one array to two other arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working on a game project and I'm trying to create an onclick event that moves the .character div from one array to two others. I'm trying to move a max of 4 characters. Since it's two separate screens I could transition from the character array to the party array and then move the party to an inCombat array. I am utilizing jQuery with the javascript. Code is a mess right now but I'll show you what I've got.

HTML:

```
<section id="team-character-select">
            <p class="select-button-contain"><button id="char-select">Char Select</button></p>
            <article id="selected-characters"></article>
        </section>

        <section id="combat-arena">
            <article id="player-section">
                <div class="player-characters" id="attacker-one"></div>
                <div class="player-characters" id="attacker-two"></div>
                <div class="player-characters" id="attacker-three"></div>
                <div class="player-characters" id="attacker-four"></div>
            </article>
```

JS:

```
var characters = {
    "Guy1": {
            name: "Guy1",
            health: 120,
            attack: 8
        }
};

    var attacker1;
    var attacker2;
    var attacker3;
    var attacker4;

    var party = ["", "", "", ""]; // 4
    var unUsed = [];

var renderCharacter = function (character, renderArea) {
        // this block of code builds the character card, and renders it to the page.
        var charDiv = $("<div class='character' data-name='" + character.name + "'>");
        var charName = $("<div class='character-name'>").text(character.name);
        var charImage = $("<img alt='image' class='character-image'>").attr("src", character.imageUrl);
        var charHealth = $("<div class='character-health'>").text(character.health);
        charDiv.append(charName).append(charImage).append(charHealth);
        $(renderArea).append(charDiv);

    };

    var initializeGame = function () {
        $("#start-game").click(function () {
            // Loop through the characters object and call the renderCharacter function on each character to render their card
            for (var key in characters) {
                renderCharacter(characters[key], "#team-character-select");
            }
        }, )
    };


    initializeGame();



    $(".character").click(function () {
        party.push(".character");
        document.getElementById("#selected-characters").innerHTML = party;
        console.log(party);
    });
```

Comment: you can make a working demo of the code will make life easier for everyone.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam You mean like codepen?

https://codepen.io/haxxor_man/pen/qYxbaP